# How to get general link field properties in Sitecore Powershell Extensions

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore8.2

Using SPE (Sitecore Powershell Extensions) I need an Item's general link type field "Url" property, but have been running into problems converting the type.

I've tried to convert Item property to `Linkfield` object like this:

```
[Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$field = $myolditem["Email"]
```

**Output:**

> Error converting string to Linkfield

How do I convert the string value of the field to a `Linkfield` type using SPE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
[Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$field = $myolditem.Fields["Email"]
$Url = $field.Url
```

You should get the Url of the Link

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of Links : Internal, External, Media Links etc.

In case if you want to retrieve URLs irrespective of link types, please use the below lines..

```
[Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.LinkUrl]$fieldLink = New-Object -TypeName 'Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.LinkUrl'
$Url = $fieldLink.GetUrl($myolditem, "Email")
```